# AttributeError: 'rational_resampler_ccc' object has no attribute 'connect' GNUradio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Help solve the problem with GNUradio

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pedro/DOPLOM/signal.py", line 166, in <module>
main()
  File "/home/pedro/DOPLOM/signal.py", line 142, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "/home/pedro/DOPLOM/signal.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.rational_resampler_xxx_1 = filter.rational_resampler_ccc(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/filter/rational_resampler.py", line 150, in __init__
    _rational_resampler_base.__init__(self, filter.rational_resampler_base_ccc,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/filter/rational_resampler.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.connect(self, self.resampler, self)
AttributeError: 'rational_resampler_ccc' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

[image]

Comment: which version of GNU Radio is this?

Comment: GNU Radio 3.8.2.0

Comment: Hm, I tried, but I can't reproduce the problem, also: `rational_resampler_ccc` is definitely a subclass of `gr.hier_block2`, and that *has* a `connect` method!

Comment: do you perchance have two competing installations of GNU Radio? This is the best I can guess.

Comment: I do not know what to do. I reinstalled the program, but it did not solve the problem. Initially, the program worked as expected. When I started GNUradio the next day this error started showing up

Comment: Really, sounds like you somehow have remnants of an installation somewhere around; that's not fixed by installing your mostly working version anew. Something really easy to try: boot the [GNU Radio Live VM](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/UbuntuVM) and try your thing there. If it works there, you still need to fix your system, but you'd know it's not a bug you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to reinstall Ubuntu and now everything works